# Why do I always need to clone model attributes in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm overriding the Backbone Model toJSON to reformat some data, I see _.clone() a lot and I've seen that I need to clone this.attributes. I'm not completely sure why I need to clone, can anyone explain?

**JS**

```
toJSON: function()
    var attributes = _.clone(this.attributes);

    //...
}
```

Comment: I believe this is due to fact that Backbone.Model listen for changes to attribute and fire the change/update/delete events that views can listen and re-render. Cloning assures that we are gonna work on a copy rather than the actual data holding object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since objects are passed by reference in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript),

If you do this:

```
var attributes = this.attributes;
```

Whatever changes you make to `attributes` will reflect in the actual model as well.

Most of the time this is not the desired behavior, hence the use of `_.clone` or similar utility methods